# Returning redirect as response to Ajax (fetch, XHR, etc.) request

Tags: ajax, http

What happens if the browser receives a redirect response to an ajax request?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8905545/248058

Comment: Possible workaround here in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177252/detecting-a-redirect-in-ajax-request/77560594#77560594

Answer (score 239, accepted):

*What happens if the browser receives a redirect response to an ajax request?*

If the server sends a redirect (aka a 302 response plus a Location: header) the redirect is automatically followed by the browser. The response to the *second* request (assuming it also isn't another redirect) is what is exposed to your program.

In fact, you don't have the ability to detect whether a 302 response has occurred. If the 302 redirect leads to a 200, then your program acts identically as if the original request led directly to a 200.

This has been both my experience and the [behavior called out in the spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method).

**2016 Update:** Time has passed, and the good news is that the new [fetch() API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) is spec'd to offer [finer-grained control of how redirects are handled](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode), with default behavior similar to XHR. That said, it only works where fetch() is implemented *natively*. [Polyfill versions of fetch()](https://github.com/github/fetch)—which are based on XHR—[continue to have XHR's limitations](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/137). Fortunately, [native browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) seems to be rounding out nicely.

Comment: Interestingly, I arrived at this because I am experiencing a situation where the redirect is apparently not being followed... this happens when the redirect violates same origin policy.

Comment: @Gus which is probably logical

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the redirect leads to a 401 instead of a 200?  I seem to be running into that issue and getting errors with jQuery, so I am trying to figure out exactly what the brower/JS is supposed to be doing.

Comment: In the case of a redirect to a 401 (or any 4xx or 5xx error) I'd assume your program would behave as if the request led directly to a 401. Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: A RESTful API may send 201 and a Location header after a POST request; see http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html.

Comment: What about headers? To they follow the redirection? Can I define this behavior?

Comment: If requestA redirects to requestB, then your code will only be able to see headers belonging to requestB.

Comment: If it's any help: I know that my `window.location.pathname.split('/').length` should be the same length as the parsed and prepared **xhttp.responseURL**. So if it's not the same length, it is _probably_ a redirect – in my case. But thinking about it: if you know the URL and expect your response to be from the _same URL_, then you could just compare your expected URL with the _xhttp.responseURL_.

Comment: for those who are using the fetch library by github, please note that follow redirect is not working.

https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/137

Comment: 2019 update: fetch doesn't work as we were expecting 3 years ago ):

Answer (score 7):

The `ajax-request` will follow that redirect afaik. The actual content (`.responseText`, `.responseXML`) will be the content from the page you are redirected to.

You might be able to intercept the redirect (`status-code`, `location-header`) on `readyState` 2 or 3, but not sure about it.

Comment: Nope, all those states carry the exact same status. Even the value of `getAllResponseHeaders()` is equal.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: it's doable with `fetch`.
More info here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932#issuecomment-515229573