# JSONP callback doesn't execute when running at localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost, jsonp, xss

This is bizarre, I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on why this happened.

Basically, I've been pulling my hair out trying to test JSONP out so I can implement a JSON web service that other sites can use. I'm doing development on localhost--specifically, Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2008's built-in web server.

So as a JSONP test run w/ jQuery, I implemented the following:

```
$().ready(function() {
  debugger;
  try {
    $.getJSON("<%= new Uri(Request.Url, "/").ToString() %>XssTest?callback=?", function(data) {
        alert(data.abc);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

And on the server ..

```
<%= Request["callback"] %>({abc : 'def'})
```

So what ends up happening is I set a breakpoint on the server and I get the breakpoint both on the first "debugger;" statment in the client-side script as well as on the server. The JSONP URL is indeed being invoked after the page loads. That's working great.

The problem I was having was that the callback would never execute. I tested this in both IE8 as well as Firefox 3.5. Neither one would invoke the callback. The catch(err) was never reached, either. Nothing happened at all!

I'd been stuck on this for a week, and even tested with a manually keyed HTTP request in Telnet on the specified port to be sure that the server is returning the format...

```
callbackfn({abc : 'def'})
```

.. and it is.

Then it dawned on me, what if I change the hostname from localhost to localhost with a globalizer ('.'), i.e http://localhost.:41559/ instead of http://localhost:41559/ (yes, adding a dot to any hostname is legal, it is to DNS what `global::` is to C# namespaces). And then it worked! Internet Explorer and Firefox 3.5 finally showed me an alert message when I just added a dot.

So this makes me wonder, what is going on here? Why would late script tag generation work with an Internet hostname and not with plain localhost? Or is that the right question?

Clearly this is implemented for security reasons, but what are they trying to secure?? And, by getting it to work with a dot, did I just expose a security hole in this security feature?

By the way, my hosts file, while altered for other hosts, has nothing special going on with localhost; the default 127.0.0.1 / ::1 are still in place with no overrides below.

**FOLLOW-UP:** I got past this for local development purposes by adding:

```
127.0.0.1   local.mysite.com
```

.. to my hosts file, then adding the following code to my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Headers["Host"].Split(':')[0] == "localhost")
    {
        Response.Redirect(
            Request.Url.Scheme
            + "://"
            + "local.mysite.com"
            + ":" + Request.Url.Port.ToString()
            + Request.Url.PathAndQuery
            , true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use tools like firebug and see if the "script" request is being done for the JSONP stuff, and actually see what data is coming back.

Comment: The data was valid. As described, the workaround was to get away from localhost (script and data otherwise stayed the same) and that "fixed" it, but doesn't fully explain what's going on.

Comment: yes, that's why i suggest logging the happenings for the unfixed version.

Comment: I did, Luca. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I wonder if this is relevant: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=560594

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to throw an answer out there; after some thought I've reached my own conclusions.

It could be that this is a security feature that's implemented to try to thwart an Internet web site from invoking JSONP services running on the client machine.

A web site could just go through a list of ports and keep invoking localhost on different ports and paths. 'Localhost' is one of few DNS hostnames that are dynamic in meaning depending on when and where it's queried, making the potential targets vulnerable. And yes, the fact that appending a dot (.) to 'localhost' ('localhost.') produces a working workaround does expose a security vulnerability, but does offer a [tentative] workaround for development puposes.

A better approach is to map the loopback IP to a new hostname entry in the hosts file so that it works locally, isn't prone to be "fixed" by a browser update, and doesn't work anywhere else but on the development workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing a similar problem. Most of the solutions I've tried work with IE (7), but I'm having difficulty getting Firefox (3.5.2) to play ball.

I've installed HttpFox in order to see how my server's responses are being interpreted on the client, and I'm getting NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI. My situation is a little different to yours though, as I'm trying to invoke a JSONP call back to the same site the hosting page came from, and then this call is responding with a 302 redirect to another site. (I'm using the redirect as a convenient way to get cookies from both domains returned to the browser.)

I'm using jQuery, and I originally tried doing a standard AJAX call via $.ajax(). I figured that as the initial request was to the same site as the hosting page, Firefox would just follow the 302 response to another domain. But no, it appeared to fall foul of XSS defenses. (Note that contrary to what [Returning redirect as response to XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request) implies, jQuery does follow the 302 redirect for a standard dataType="json" call: a redirect to the same domain works fine; a redirect to another domain generates NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI in the browser.) As an aside, I don't see why same-domain 302 redirects to other domains can't just be followed - after all, it's the hosting page's domain that is issuing the redirect, so why can't it be trusted? If you're worried about scripting injection attacks, then the JSONP route is open for abuse anyway...

jQuery's $.getJSON() with a ?callback=? suffix also fails in Firefox with the same error. As does using $.getScript() to roll my own JSONP <script> tag.

What does appear to work, is having a pre-existing <script id="jsonp" type="text/javascript"></script> in the HTML and then using $("jsonp").attr("src", url + "?callback=myCallback") to invoke the JSONP call. If I do that, then the cross-domain 302 redirect is followed and I get my JSON response passed to myCallback (which I've defined at the same time as the <script/> tag).

And, yes, I'm developing all this using Cassini with localhost:*port* URLs. Cassini won't respond to non-localhost URLs, so I can't easily try local.mysite.com to see if that has any affect on the solutions I've tried above. However, sticking a dot at the end of localhost appears to have fixed all my problems!

Now I can go back to a standard $.ajax({ ... dataType:"jsonp" ... }) call with localhost__.__:*port* instead of localhost:*port* and all is well. I find it interesting that modifying the src attribute of a script tag that pre-exists in the page's HTML *does* allow ordinary localhost URLs to be invoked - I guess following your thought process, this could be another security vulnerability.