# JSONP & http://localhost.:<port>/

Tags: security, xss, jsonp

After reading **[JSONP callback doesn't execute when running at localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217926/jsonp-callback-doesnt-execute-when-running-at-localhost)** and googling a lot, I am still unclear if there is a potential XSS security threat.

Is this "hole" covered in popular browsers nowadays?

(notice the `dot` in the URI)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a potential security flaw, just be smart with your coding to check for XSS... I'm not sure but I think Firefox4 blocks this hole...