# ASP MVC and jsonp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonp

I need to send some data through a Jsonp response from a MVC application. For Jsonp response method i used a JsonpFilter.

This is my Jsonp response method:

```
[JsonpFilter]
    public JsonResult GetPageName()
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = Session["Page"],
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

and this is the javascript function:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: 'http://localhost:54845/Login/GetPageName',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.width + "-" + data.height);
            }
        });
```

This code works great only on FF. In IE nothing is happening.

What is wrong in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with IE session variables.
If i replace Session["Page"] with new {var1 = "var1", var2 = "var2"} it works.
So i need to find a solution for that.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually planning on making cross-domain HTTP GETs of JSON data?  If not, why bother with JSONP?  Just use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is being loosey goosey. The other browsers are being prude dudes.

See: [JSONP callback doesn't execute when running at localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217926/jsonp-callback-doesnt-execute-when-running-at-localhost)

To quote:

> A web site could just go through a
>   list of ports and keep invoking
>   localhost on different ports and
>   paths. 'Localhost' is one of few DNS
>   hostnames that are dynamic in meaning
>   depending on when and where it's
>   queried, making the potential targets
>   vulnerable. And yes, the fact that
>   appending a dot (.) to 'localhost'
>   ('localhost.') produces a working
>   workaround does expose a security
>   vulnerability, but does offer a
>   [tentative] workaround for development
>   puposes.
>
> A better approach is to map the
>   loopback IP to a new hostname entry in
>   the hosts file so that it works
>   locally, isn't prone to be "fixed" by
>   a browser update, and doesn't work
>   anywhere else but on the development
>   workstation.

Answer (score 0):

### MVC / JSONP / DataSet Binding

I was able to get JSONP to work with MVC by modifying the code above. This sample directly binds datasets to html elements via JSONP.

### Controller

>

> public class HomeController : Controller
>      {
>          [HttpGet]
>          public ActionResult HeaderJSONP()
>          {
>              DsPromotion.HeaderDataTable tbl = new DsPromotion.HeaderDataTable();
>              DsPromotion.HeaderRow row = tbl.NewHeaderRow();
>              row.imgBanner_src = "/Content/Home/Image/MainBanner.gif";
>              tbl.Rows.Add(row);
>              return new JsonpResult { Data = tbl };
>          }
>      }

### JSONP Result

```
> public class JsonpResult : System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
>    {
>        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>        {
>            this.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
>            if (context == null)
>            {
>                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
>            }
>
>            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
>            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
>            {
>                response.ContentType = ContentType;
>            }
>            else
>            {
>                response.ContentType = "application/json";
>            }
>            if (ContentEncoding != null)
>            {
>                response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
>            }
>            if (Data != null)
>            {
>                HttpRequestBase request = context.HttpContext.Request;
>                JavaScriptSerializer jsonserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
>                DataTableConverter serializer = new DataTableConverter();
>                response.Write(request.Params["jsoncallback"] + "(" + jsonserializer.Serialize(serializer.Serialize(Data, new JavaScriptSerializer())) + ")");
>            }
>        }
>    }
```

### Javascript / JQuery JSON Request and Callback

>

> function BindDataTable(dataTable) {
>      var tableName;
>      for (tableName in dataTable) {
>          if (tableName.indexOf('*') > 0) {
>              tableName = tableName.split('*')[0];
>          }
>      }
>      var elementAndAttrib;
>      for (elementAndAttrib in dataTable[tableName][0]) {
>          var elementID = elementAndAttrib.split('*')[0];
>          var attribName = elementAndAttrib.split('*')[1];
>          var attribValue = dataTable[tableName][0][elementAndAttrib];
>          $("#" + elementID).attr(attribName, attribValue);
>      }
>   }
>   function GetHomeHeaderCallBack(tblHeader) {
>      BindDataTable(tblHeader);
>   }
>   function GetHomeHeader() {
>      var call = "/Home/HeaderJSONP?jsoncallback=?&" + Math.round(new Date().getTime());
>      $.getJSON(call, { format: "json" }, GetHomeHeaderCallBack);
>   }
>   $(GetHomeHeader);

### Partial View

> <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

### XSD

...

### Table Serializer

>

> public class DataTableConverter : JavaScriptConverter
>      {
>          public override IEnumerable SupportedTypes
>          {
>              get { return new Type[] { typeof(DataTable) }; }
>          }
>
> ```
>    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type,
>    JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
>    {
>        throw new NotImplementedException();
>    }
>
>    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
>    {
>        DataTable listType = obj as DataTable;
>
>        if (listType != null)
>        {
>            // Create the representation.
>            Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
>            ArrayList itemsList = new ArrayList();
>            foreach (DataRow row in listType.Rows)
>            {
>                //Add each entry to the dictionary.
>                Dictionary<string, object> listDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
>                foreach (DataColumn dc in listType.Columns)
>                {
>                    listDict.Add(dc.ColumnName, row[dc.ColumnName].ToString());
>                }
>                itemsList.Add(listDict);
>            }
>            result[listType.TableName] = itemsList;
>
>            return result;
>        }
>        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Enjoy!
Mark Brito