# How to get redirect URL using an AJAX Request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a problem.. in my project, i need to make an AJAX request to a URL shortener site (such as bit.ly, etc..).

My target is either I could get the redirect URL or the content of the redirected site. This far, after I tried some techniques from the web, I still cannot get the correct result.

I tried to catch the 301 HTTP response status (the default behaviour of URL shortener sites), but I found that the request never returns 301. Strangely, it returns 200.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: The 200 is because the request automatically follows the 301. I don't know whether that can be turned off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method) quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request) a 30x header will automatically be followed and there is no way to get hold of the redirecting resource from within an Ajax call:

> The same-origin request event rules are as follows:
>
> If the response has an HTTP status code of 301, 302, 303, or 307
>       If the redirect violates infinite loop precautions this is a network error.
>
> Otherwise, run these steps:
>
> - Set the request URL to the URL conveyed by the Location header.
> - If the XMLHttpRequest origin and the origin of request URL are same origin transparently follow the redirect while observing the same-origin request event rules.
> - Otherwise, follow the cross-origin request steps and terminate the steps for this algorithm.

You will probably need to use a server-side solution for this.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... yes, I think server-side scripting will help too... But, unfortunately in my project, i can't use any server side scripting... only client-side scripting allowed.. :(

Comment: @Abou Maybe somebody manages to come up with some genius way I can't see, but I don't think you can do this on the client side alone.