# What is the exact response structure for HTTP status code 300 (Multiple Choices)?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-codes

When a user clicks a link to a drawing on my site `http://mysite.com/some-drawing`,
I would like my server to respond with status code 300 and two resource locations: `http://mysite.com/some-drawing.png` and `http://mysite.com/some-drawing.myapp`, and have the client browser decide automatically which one to use, based on its capabilities:

- If MyApp is installed on the user's machine, then the browser should download the `*.myapp` version and use MyApp to display it.
- However, if MyApp is not installed, and the browser is incapable to display this version, then I would like it to pick the `*.png` version.

However, I am having a hard time figuring out the structure of a HTTP response with status code 300.

The [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.1) says:

> The requested resource corresponds to any one of a set of
>   representations, each with its own specific location, and agent-
>   driven negotiation information (section 12) is being provided so that
>   the user (or user agent) can select a preferred representation and
>   redirect its request to that location.
>
> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity
>   containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from
>   which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The
>   entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-
>   Type header field. Depending upon the format and the capabilities of 
>   the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be
>   performed automatically. However, this specification does not define
>   any standard for such automatic selection.
>
> If the server has a preferred choice of representation, it SHOULD
>   include the specific URI for that representation in the Location
>   field; user agents MAY use the Location field value for automatic
>   redirection. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

The wording "*entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s)*" seems ambiguous. What does it mean? Does anybody know how this is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That won't work.

The "multiple choices" are done by sending the links in hypertext (HTML) content and let the *user* pick.

Comment: The rfc says: "Depending upon the format and the capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be performed automatically".
Are you saying that all the major browsers treat all status 300 responses the same by prompting the user for manual choosing?

Comment: Yes. Do you know a format that would *allow* the user agent to choose for you?

Comment: For example: a "multipart/alternative" metia type entity. This is at least what is being used by email clients to determine the best choice to present to the user.

Comment: But that's a format for encoding alternative content, not *links* to alternative content...

Comment: The "multipart/alternative" media type does not specify the types of the alternatives. Each of the alternatives has a mime type of its own. This mime type may be for example, "application/http", and include an http entity such as "HTTP/1.1 307 Moved\n\rLocation: //mysite.com/some-drawing.myapp". However, this seems overly cumbersome for something like this, plus I'm not sure how would the browser choose in this case. But this is only one option; there may be others.

Comment: Okay, after not being able to find information re how do major browsers handle status code 300, I've downloaded the webkit source code and searched for the answer myself. It seems that webkit handles status 300 like the other redirection status codes: redirect according to the Location header, or present an error to the user if this header is missing. So, it seems that @Julian-Reschke was right after all: My solution doesn't work. :-(

Answer (score 4):

In theory, if a client supported server-driven negotiation, you could send back various 'Accept-*' headers, but those are rather limited (eg, Languauge, Encoding, Charset), and could be used for 'do you want the PDF or MS Word document?' or 'Would you like that in Spanish or English?'), but not for other arbitrary distinctions.  I'm not aware of any browsers that support it.  Instead, they have the browser send the Accept headers, and the server respond with whatever it thinks is best.

See :

- [RFC 2295, "Transparent Content Negotiation in HTTP"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2295)
- [RFC 2616, "HTTP/1.1" section 12 "Content Negotiation"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-12) (for problems related to server-driven content negotiation)

**update** :

Also see [Mozilla Developer Network's "Content negotiation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation), which discusses some advantage and disadvantages of server-drive vs. client-driven negotiation, and some additional headers that may be of interest (eg, looking to see if the client sends 'Negotiate' to announce what it supports)