# Running JavaScript downloaded with XMLHttpRequest recursively

Tags: javascript, ajax, scripting, download

Is it possible to change this code, so it will work recursively if the http://www.myurl.com redirect to the js file that should run?

```
function include(scriptUrl)
{
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", scriptUrl);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if ((xmlhttp.status == 200) && (xmlhttp.readyState == 4))
            {
                eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send();
}
include("http://www.myurl.com");
```

Comment: No, this is done automatically, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/282429/1048572

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do:

```
$("head").append("<script src='http://myurl.com' type='text/javascript'></script>");
```

Of course you can do it without jquery but that's the jist of it. If you're just pulling from a URL that only requires GET arguments (if any at all) then it's easier (and safer) to just add a new script element that includes it.

This will also take care of your redirection issue since the browser will follow the redirect.

Comment: The redirect would have been followed with XHR, too, but it is true that a script insertion is better than what the OP tries

Comment: If you are going for jQuery you could consider using [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: Why? Is there some requirement you've not told us about?

Comment: Its for pulling data not only js. please read below my comment to Jasper de Vries

Comment: You could still use jQuery for that. Just `eval` the `data` returned by [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Answer (score 1):

When the URL redirects you to another location it will probably give you a 301 [status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) instead of a 200 status. In that case your check should be:

```
if ((xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.status == 301) && xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
```

Or you can choose to allow all but the error statuses:

```
if (xmlhttp.status < 400 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
```

Comment: It doesn't eval the js when adding this statuses. I tried to add 'else if' for status 301 and then calling include with the new url but after its eval the script (let's say the script is: alert("hello");) its continue to call it again with "www.example.com/alert("hello); for some reason.. any suggests?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` of `xmlhttp`? Is the status as expected? Do you get a `responseText`?

Comment: well I don't know why but after including this 'else if' and writing it: ((xmlhttp.status == 301) && (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)) - checking that the state is 4 its working! it didn't work before but who remember what I wrote before :)