# Form with 'remote: true' return a 200 response even with redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with `remote: true` like this:

```rb
<%= form_with model: @transfer, scope: :transfer, url: transfers_path, method: 'post', remote: true do |f| %>
```

And my controller `create` action looks like this:

```rb
def create
  @transfer = @account.transfers.build(transfer_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @transfer.save
      format.html { redirect_to transfers_path }
    else
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

If I submit a form with no errors, the page does redirect like expected. However, I noticed that the server responded with a status code of 200, instead of 302. My server log looks like this:

```
Started POST "/transfers" for ::1 at 2019-06-04 08:32:22 -0700
Processing by TransfersController#create as JS
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/transfers
Completed 200 OK in 1476ms (ActiveRecord: 81.2ms)

Started GET "/transfers" for ::1 at 2019-06-04 08:32:23 -0700
Processing by TransfersController#index as HTML
```

Just wondering why it's a 200 and not a 302? I also realized that this never should've worked because I shouldn't be able to redirect with an AJAX request (`remote: true` sends an AJAX request if I understand it right).

Answers on other questions on SO seems to suggest that `redirect_to` won't work, and I'd have to use JS to set the window location for redirect. Some example answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23433009/3504731
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601358/3504731
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16098942/3504731

I'm confused on why my code is working. Can anyone shed some lights on this? I'm suspecting [`rails-ujs`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) is doing some magic behind the scene but I'm not sure. Specifically, I suspect [these lines](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L72-L75) but I'm not too good at JS and I couldn't parse much of it. I am also running Rails 5.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `form_with` doesn't use `remote`, it uses `local` and it's set to `false` by default, that is, like `form_for` with `remote: true`.

Second, `respond_to` doesn't work as you think it works. You don't choose the response format, the client does.

If the client sends a regular HTTP request (`remote: false`), then your `create` responds with the block after `format.html`. If the client sends an AJAX request (`remote: true`), then `create` responds with the `format.js` part.

There is not a redirect because `format.html { redirect_to transfers_path }` is never run since you are issuing an AJAX request.

Check *response* in the *network* tab of your browser's devel tools to find out what's really going on.

Also, refactor your method:

```rb
def create
  @transfer = @account.transfers.build(transfer_params)
  saved = @transfer.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      if saved
        redirect_to transfers_path
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Error'
        render :new
      end
    end
    format.js # Create app/views/<controller>/create.js.erb and
              # update page there
  end
end
```

Comment: There is a redirect going on. My page does go to the `/transfers` after I posted a transfer successfully. That's the part I'm most confused about. I do also have a `create.js.erb` in place but it is strictly to handle errors and I found that even if I remove that file, the page still redirects after I posted a transfer and still responded with a 200 code.

Comment: Did you check the _network_ tab of the devel tools? What's the response? What's its type?

Comment: Yes I checked the network tab, the response has a type of `xhr` and status of `200`.

Comment: What about this redirect: `Redirected to http://localhost:3000/transactions/pending`? Is action `pending` issuing the `get index`?

Comment: Ah I'm so sorry I realized I copied the wrong route. I've edited my question but `http://localhost:3000/transactions/pending` was supposed to be `http://localhost:3000/transfers` instead. My `Transfers#create` is redirecting to `Transfer#index`.

Comment: I'll setup a new app and try to reproduce it