# Handle JSON events in Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

i have searched in google and on stackoverflow and could find a good answer.

i have that code on my HTML page that gets HTML output of python(i'm using jquery):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getHTML.py",
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('body').append(response);
    }
});
```

python file looks like that:

```
baseHTML = "www.google.com"
user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)"
headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent}
req = urllib2.Request(baseHTML, headers=headers)

forumHTML = urllib2.urlopen(req)

page = Soup(forumHTML)

for e in page.findAll('script'):
    e.extract()

print 'Content-Type: text/plain\r'
print '\r'
print page
```

Every thing works and i'm happy, But... now i tried to add another JSON that sent by a button click event:

```
$('#GetByURL_button').on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "getHTML.py",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"newURL": "www.stackoverflow.com"),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

and now i just don't know how to handle that event in python.

So just to be clear - i want python to have something like:

1. if user didn't ask for anything(via JSON) load default page,
2. if user asked for "stackoverflow"(via JSON) load www.stackoverflow.com
3. if user asked for "dog" load www.DogsAreCool.com.

tnx for the help :)

Comment: What kind of server are you running? A generic web server running Python scripts via WSGI or CGI or mod_python? A standard Python web server? Something custom?

Comment: Have you looked at [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/)?

Comment: are you trying to write a `proxy` using python?

Comment: Is there a strong reason to try to use the same url for serving two different responses? My recommendation would be to use routing: different urls serve different responses

Comment: @fp - tnx, i'm now using Bottle, its great and easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what framework or mechanism you're using to hook up Python scripts, and your sample doesn't show the script handling input at all.

So, let's assume you're using a mechanism that gives you the request body as `stdin`, like old-school CGI. You'd do something like this:

```
content = sys.stdin.read()
data = json.loads(content)
newURL = data.get('newURL')
if newURL == 'dog':
    newURL = 'http://www.DogsAreCool.com'
elif not newURL:
    newURL = defaultPageURL
response = urllib2.urlopen(newURL)
# ...
```

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, definitely. But the framework is at best going to turn the first two lines into one line (if you're using a framework that will call your function with an object instead of running your script with `stdin`), so most of the code (trivial as it is) will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

- your server send backs the correct URL via a normal http response (200 OK)
- your ajax code sets `window.location`
- your browser is happy to redirect

Second one:

- your server sends a redirect response with correct `location` header.
- your [ajax request will follow the redirect and return the correct content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request).
- your ajax inserts content in the DOM.