# Firefox 30.0, error message page moved temperarily

Tags: firefox, getjson

I was using `jQuery.getJSON("EXAMPLE.json");` to get the json from the same domain, the actual json file is on Amazon cloud. Now I have these results:

**Firefox 30.0:**

code on remote server: doesn't work, throws message: `302 moved temperarily`.

code on localhost: works fine.

**earlier Firefox and other browsers:**

works fine on either remote server and localhost.

Anybody know if it's a bug on firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because Firefox denies the request since it seems like your local EXAMPLE.json just reidrects to the Amazon file. [[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#comment24005605_2573589)

I am not familiar with how Amazon cloud works, but if you have access to change the HTTP headers the server responds with you should add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the Amazon server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your.owm.domain
```