# Is it possible the discover the redirected URL in an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

What is the expected behavior by all browsers when an XHR receives a redirect ?

- Can it see the "redirected" (final) url ?
- Is it possible to hide the redirected url ?
- Is this behavior the same for all major browsers (Safari, i.e. ;), Chrome, Firefox)

Is there a standard spec, and how does one test this ?

This: [Returning redirect as response to XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request) question doesn't say if the browser can see it, and the link to the spec is broken.

EDIT: Also, what happens if redirected to a url in a different domain, or even a subdomain , or even multiple redirects ?

Comment: I don't see a broken link on that question or answer. Which link is broken? (I can probably fix it, if you point it out.)

Comment: It appears that the link is working now, but yesterday there was some kind of server error.