# How to redirect after fopen() in php

Tags: php

I have issue to redirect another location after fopen() function in php. below is my function which i m using.

```
<?php
function create_file($filename){
    $my_file = 'folder/index.php';
    $fh = fopen($my_file, "wb");
    $data = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Some data</title>
   </head>
    <body>Here some data</body>
            </html>';
  fwrite($fh, $data);
        fclose($fh);
return true;
ob_end_clean(); 
exit();
}
$file = create_file(test);
if($file == true){
   $url = 'http://example.com';
   return $url;
}
else{
return 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: i m getting nothing. no any error is coming if i comment this function then header location is working well. in backend file is created in folder but header location not working.

Comment: At the top of your script add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect in `PHP`, you **cannot send any `output`** to the server before `header("Location: http://example.com");`.

This includes any HTML, text or white spaces that aren't wrapped in a `PHP` tag set.

Comment: if i call create_file() after header location then file not created in backend :(

Comment: have you tried using a `Javascript` redirect instead?

Comment: actually i m using ajax post method with json here in create_file() i m returing filename and in ajax after post submission i m redirect on file name. in ajax.

Comment: Yep, you could use JS redirection. Or call the createfile function in an ajax call. Or also try calling ob_start( ); at the start of the page (before anything) and ob_end_flush( ); at the end (after anything) to control when the content is output (but I'm not 100% on that).

Comment: its not working with ajax if i use it with direct php code only then its working well. i have problem with ajax code

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589

Comment: Also - are you trying to redirect to a link that is outside of your domain?

Answer (score 0):

The header function must be called before any page output (if HTML has already been displayed, it's too late for your headers!).

Comment: if i call create_file() after header location then file not created in backend :(