# Is it possible to get page redirect information via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Without ajax, if we load `http://example.com/1` and if it redirects to `http://example.com/2` then the browser gets appropriate headers and the Browser URL get's updated. Is there a way to get this information via jQuery Ajax?

For example, I am requesting  `http://api.example.com` via Ajax. In PHP, this page is redirected to `http://api2.example.com`. Is it possible to know this thing?

**Use:**
I have a navbar which has links. All pages are **loaded into the container via AJAX** and I push the url on Browser Bar using HTML5 history as per the link.

However, if the page gets redirected, the page would have a new link right? I would like to change that in the Browser bar too. I would like to know where the Ajax URL is redirected in case it is redirected.

**Why this is important?**
My links handle form data, requests and various authentications. For example, if I request, `https://oauth.example.org?code=56hycf86` it either redirects to `success` or `failure` page. My Ajax get the right html content but the URL browser bar still has the URL with same `Auth ID` which, if reloaded, produces error. There are other security issues too.

I do not know if I explained things right, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Using JavaScript, `window.location.href = NEW_URL` will do...Your question is not quiet clear...

Comment: No you can not do this cross browser. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question with use. I would like to know where the Ajax URL is redirected in case it is redirected.

Comment: Yes..I understood that but you haven't explained why you need the final url. Edit to question doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question with use. Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589 might help.

Comment: Why you get this "reload error" after the `https://oauth.example.org?code=56hycf86` request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, unfortunately, ajax always follows redirects. However, there is a feature that is not supported in all browsers, you can access the responseURL property of the XMLHttpRequest object.

You can try it in the below code snippet. the redirect button sends ajax request to a URL that replies with 1 redirect (it also works if there are multiple redirects).
The no redirect button sends ajax request to a URL with no redirects.

As far as I know this method is not supported in IE 11 and older versions of chrome/firefox/opera browsers.

```js
document.getElementById("no-redirect").addEventListener("click", function() {
  testRedirect("https://httpbin.org/get");
});

document.getElementById("redirect").addEventListener("click", function() {
  testRedirect("https://httpbin.org/redirect/1");
});


function testRedirect(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (url != xhr.responseURL) {
        alert("redirect detected to: " + xhr.responseURL)
      } else {
        alert("no redirect detected")

      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<button id="redirect">
  Redirect
</button>
<button id="no-redirect">
  No Redirect
</button>
```

Comment: This results in
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'shortened/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it will help you get a similar effect.

If you are in control of what the page `http://api.example.com` does, you could change the way it reacts when it gets a call via AJAX.

You could include a variable in your AJAX call, marking it as such a call, and if this variable is present, not redirect to an other page, but include the URL it would redirect to, in the answer.

The data returned in the AJAx call could be a hash, in which one key represents the redirect url.

```
data = {status => 1, redirect => 'http://ap2.example.com', …}
```

(Sorry if that is not a valid PHP hash)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understood it, but just tried something, if it is not what you're looking for please notify me to delete the answer.

here we inject this **`/#/`** in the URL so when clicking on links the browser will have a new segment in the URL which represent the parameter that depending on its value you can determine which page to load using the corresponding AJAX call..

**JS/jQuery:**

```js
var navLinks = $('#nav a'),
    params = [],
    baseURL = '//localhost/test/js-url-parameters-second';

navLinks.each(function(){
    var oldHREF = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', baseURL +'/#/'+ oldHREF);
});

navLinks.on('click', function(){
    checkURL($(this).attr('href'));
});

function checkURL(docURL){
    // if /#/ found then we have URL parameters
    // grabbing the parameters part of the URL
    if(docURL.indexOf('/#/') > -1){
        docURL = docURL.split('/#/')[1];
        if(docURL != ''){
            // omit the last forward slash if exists
            if(docURL[docURL.length - 1] == '/'){
                docURL = docURL.substring(0, docURL.length - 1);
            }
            console.log(docURL);
            $('#page-type').text(docURL);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('No URL parameters found');
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
  <a href="home" data-name="Home">Home</a>
  <a href="about" data-name="About">About</a>
  <a href="contact" data-name="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="container">
  this is the <span id="page-type">Home</span> page
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the already mentioned [`responseURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) doesn't have the best browser support yet, there are 2 more alternative for this case that could be used, http request headers and cookies.

The benefit with these is they don't interfere with the content itself, like for example query string keys, hash tags or embedded in the response data.

---

Request headers

Server side

- PHP

  ```
  $req->addHeader("X-Response-Url", "....");
  ```
- ASP

  ```
  headers.Add("X-Response-Url", "....");
  ```

Client side

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {

    var resp_url = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Response-Url");

    if (send_url != resp_url) {
      // redirected
    }

  }
}
```

---

Cookies

- PHP

  ```
  setcookie("XResponseUrl", "...");
  ```
- ASP

  ```
  Response.Cookies("XResponseUrl") = "..."
  ```

Client side

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {

    var resp_url = getCookie("XResponseUrl");

    if (send_url != resp_url) {
      // redirected
    }

  }
}


function getCookie(name) {
  var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
  var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
  return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, when you request http://api.example.com using Ajax, browser does not redirect. You can get all the response using jQuery like bellow

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.example.com",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is not what is being asked. the request is being redirected and OP wants to know where

Comment: @ThanhKiều I guess that gives me code the integer status code.