# How to get obtain redirected link using JavaScipt?

Tags: javascript, image, api, redirect, browser

I'm trying to access [Unsplash Source](https://source.unsplash.com/) to get random images. When you open the link https://source.unsplash.com/random, you get redirected to a random image with a random link as follows
`https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614607660006-945b019c188a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max`

Is there any way I can obtain the random redirected link ie something like  `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614607660006-945b019c188a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max`? Because I need to store it in a variable.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35570850/4903314

Answer (score 1):

My main issue was not getting random images because the browser caches the requests made to the same URL. I solved it by following this comment on Github.
https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-source-js/issues/9#issuecomment-239053606