# How to get the final redirected url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This URL:

```
https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/5190240/
```

Redirects to final URL:

```
https://zenithnovels.com/monster-refining-system/monster-refining-system-chapter-1/
```

How do I *get* the final redirected URL?

### What I've tried so far

Trying an `$.ajax()` attempt returns `undefined`:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://www.novelupdates.com/extnu/5190240/',
    async: false
  }).responseText;

alert(data);
```

What is a working way to do this?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't do that on the client side; you'd need a server component to do the request and follow the `Location` header path.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532531/is-it-possible-to-get-page-redirect-information-via-ajax

Comment: @NicoHaase It doesn't explain why `data` returns `undefined`.

Comment: What does that mean? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: That's not how [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) works

Comment: You would need a redirection service like: [WhereGoes.com](https://wheregoes.com)