# vue with axios - unwanted redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to login user.
When I send correct data

```
Vue.axios.post(context.state.userAuthLinks.login, {
     email: playload.email,
     password: playload.password
})
```

it works fine, but when I try to post wrong data, vue app reload with

http://localhost:8080/?email=asd%40gmail.com&password=asdasdasd#/

also, I found stange thing. When I, for example, sing up new user with the same email, to get error, app does not reload... It happens not only with dev server. On product server the same error.

full method

```
loginUser(context, playload) {
    return new Promise((loginResolve, loginReject) => {
        Vue.axios.post(context.state.userAuthLinks.login, {
            email: playload.email,
            password: playload.password
        }).then(function(res) {
            loginResolve(res);
            context.commit('setUserId', res.data.userId);
            context.commit('setUserToken', res.data.id);
            context.commit('setUserAuthenticated', true);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // here it don't stops with 'debugger'
            console.log(error);
            loginReject(error);
        });
    });
},
```

Also, I have theese headers

```
 Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
 Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

Comment: for example, I have User in data base asd@gmail.com and password "asd", When I send asd@gmail.com and password "asdasd"

Comment: The issue is probably in your backend, sending a redirect when the data doesn't match. AJAX requests follow redirects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589

Comment: but when i use JQuery.ajax it does not happens, also Angularjs $http does not redirect