# Redirect to a specific page in Laravel using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have created ajax function when the user clicks the button, it will check first the users profile if account is already confirmed. If not, it will redirect back to user dashboard. However, my problem now is that the page is not displayed or it is not redirecting back. The result can only be seen in the browsers' network tab.

my ajax

```
$(document).on("click", "#apply", function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: '/checkstatus',
  success: function(store){
    if(store == 'confirmed'){
      $(".apply_modal").toggleClass("open").show();
      $("body").toggleClass("open");
    }
  },

});

});
```

and my controller:

```
public function checkStatus(Request $request)
{
    $verify = Auth::user()->verifyAccount();

    if($verify == false){
        if(session()->has('verify') && session()->get('verify') != '') {
           session()->forget('verify');
        } else {
            session()->flash('verify', 'At first, please update your profile!');
        }
    }else{
        return 'confirmed';
    }

}
```

How can I properly redirect back the user to its main page? The result for now is like this.

[image]

Message to the user :

```
@if(session('verify'))
    <div class="complete_box">
        <p>{{ session('verify') }}</p>
        <a href="{{ url('/mypage') }}">Close</a>
    </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not redirect through controller if you are using ajax. you need to use javascript

```js
window.location.href = "your url";
window.location.href = "{{url('/mypage')}}";
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#apply", function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: '/checkstatus',
  success: function(store){
    if(store == 'confirmed'){
      $(".apply_modal").toggleClass("open").show();
      $("body").toggleClass("open");
      window.location.href = "your url";
    }
  },

});

});
```

for flash message use session

```php
public function checkStatus(Request $request)
{
    $verify = Auth::user()->verifyAccount();

    if($verify == false){
        \Session::put('message','At first, please update your profile!');
        return 'something you want';
    }else{
        return 'confirmed';
    }

}
```

Now in blade file where you want to show flash put this

```html
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <p class="alert alert-success">
       {!! Session::get('message') !!}
       <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    </p>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works, however, it is missing with the message `['verify' => 'At first, please update your profile!']`. How can I do it that way?

Comment: @EemJee Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589 effectively your message will be set and then consumed within the same request. You need to revise your overall logic

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma Yes. as a prompt to the user that they have to update the profile.

Comment: @EemJee please check and verify it if you facing any issue let me know

Comment: Thanks @AkashKumarVerma It works. But please check my updates in sending the user a message, the my url when the close button  is clicked is `/mypage` . My problem now, is that the modal is not closing.

Comment: are you sing bootstap model

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma Yes. I'm trying to use flash instead of put. But still the same.

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma Please check.

Comment: you made a mistake  if(ession()->has('verify') && $request->session()->get('verify') != '') {     ===========  s is missing in session

Comment: and in flash you need to use $request->session()->flash('verify', 'At first, please update your profile!');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189948/discussion-between-eem-jee-and-akash-kumar-verma).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "#apply", function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: '/checkstatus',
  success: function(store){
    if(store == 'confirmed'){
      $(".apply_modal").toggleClass("open").show();
      $("body").toggleClass("open");
      window.location.href = "store.url";
    }
  },

});

});
```

Here the store.url is that url which is coming in response.

In controller

```
Craete a url and send in response.
```