# jquery ajax post with location.href in data is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, location, http-status-code-302

What is preventing type `POST` from getting the expected result if using `location.href` (or `window.location.href`) as data?

This code is not working (it returns nothing):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'page.asp',
    data: {'q': location.href},
    success: function(short_link,status){ 
        console.log('short_link = '+short_link);
        console.log('status = '+status);
    }
});
```

[image]

I do see **q** value is sent in browser Network info, BUT somehow it looks like the POST is redirected to a GET because of an **302 Object moved** status code. Much like stated in there: [Returning redirect as response to XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request)

[image]

However, if I change it to `data: {'q': 'to some string'}` it works.

Also, if I change the code to use `GET` (and the code in `'page.asp'` accordingly) it also works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'page.asp?q='+location.href,
    success: function(short_link,status){ 
        console.log('short_link = '+short_link);
        console.log('status = '+status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Add screenshot of console

Comment: what does console show when you output `console.log(location.href);`

Comment: it shows the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place.

The `page.asp` had a check for SQL injection function that was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to encode url, to replace special chars.

Comment: I added this `contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` and set `var q = encodeURIComponent(location.host)`. Still not working.