# Execute a PHP function from within a Javascript script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've looked at all the questions on here and simply cannot get my head around this or get it to work. I simply want to use a button which runs a script that executes a php function.

HTML:

```
<button id="update_submit" type="button" onClick="myFunction()">Update</button>
```

Script:

```
                    <script>
                        function myFunction(){
                            if (document.getElementById("drug_text_name").value=="") {
                                alert( "I am an alert box!" );
                            } else {
                            $.ajax({url: "../script.php", success: function(result){
                                window.location.href = '../drug_manager.php';
                                }      
                                   });
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
// including the database connection file

    include_once("../../includes/dbh.inc.php");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE drugs SET Drug_Name='$Drug_Name' ,Allergies='$Allergies' ,Side_effects='$Side_effects' ,Type_of_Medication='$Type_of_Medication',Dosage='$Dosage' WHERE Drug_ID=$Drug_ID");

?>
```

Here, I would like it to run the SQL query, then redirect the user to the page /drug_manager.php.

Comment: Your php file is not returning json which `dataType: 'json'` says it should.  If you don't return anything, your ajax call will bomb since you are telling it it **will** return json

Comment: Also, that php file is not executing that function...... ?

Comment: Why not POST to PHP ?

Comment: @Taplar What should I put there instead of dataType:

Comment: You should address devlin's comment.  Are you wanting to redirect the page?  If so, using ajax doesn't make sense.  And if an endpoint is not returning json, don't put the dataType there.  You are not required to specify the dataType.

Comment: @devlincarnate I copy/pasted this from someone elses solution

Comment: @Taplar I'm wanting to redirect it simply as a test, so I can just make sure its working, I'm using a different function for it after I get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot execute a PHP-function within JavaScript because PHP runs on the server-side and JavaScript runs on the client-side. In your example, your PHP-file is not doing anything because the test function is never executed. If you execute the test function the ajax call will be redirected to that location, read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589).

If you want the user to be redirected when they click the button you could simply redirect them with help of window.location.href, something like this:

```
<script>
$("#update_submit").on('click', function(){
    window.location.href = '../script.php';
)};
</script>
```

If you want PHP to decide where the user should be redirected your PHP-file could return an URL and then you use window.location.href to that URL. Something like this:

PHP:

```
<?php
function test() {
    echo "drug_manager.php";
}
test();
?>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$("#update_submit").on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
       url: '../script.php',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
           window.location.href = data;
       }
    });
)};
</script>
```

Comment: Since I posted the question I changed my method, would you be able to please take a look at that? I would really appreciate it since I'm stumped at the moment.

Comment: Instead of sending an ajax request to script.php you could send the user to script.php using window.location.href = '../script.php'. In script.php you can add a line in the bottom of the script that redirects the user to drug_manager.php. Add this as the last line in your php script: header('Location: drug_manager.php');

Comment: That's an approach I did not know of. This is what I have right now: 

function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("drug_text_name").value=="") {
    alert( "I am an alert box!" );
  } else {
    window.location.href = '../script.php';
  }
}

From what I can tell, it doesn't seem to run the SQL queries

Comment: What does your PHP script look like?

Comment: I've just set up error logs, these are the errors I get: https://pastebin.com/Ua3vuMP4

Comment: Ok, so in this case, you're expecting a POST request and when you redirect someone to a page they will do a GET request. Do you have a HTML-form? The easiest way would be to post a html form like this: https://codepen.io/mikaelwallgren/pen/bGVoKJb

Comment: Yes, I do have a HTML form which shows drug data (as I'm implementing the edit form for this).