# RazorPages return RedirectToPage not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've got an odd thing happening. On my index page I've got an ajax call that grabs a parameter off of an SVG and then hits the following code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostStateClickAsync(string state)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetObject("CurrentFilters", SearchFilters);

        SearchFilters.State = state;

        return RedirectToPage("/Search");
    }
```

I'm able to attach a debugger and see everything is working fine behind the scenes. The problem, the UI doesn't ever update and take me to the Search page. If I manually navigate there all the data is loaded and everything is fine.

Not seen this behavior before and I've used the same code in previous projects.

Here is the AJAX call in case it's relevant:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('path').click(function () {
        var stateParameter = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Index?handler=StateClick&state=' + stateParameter,
            //data: searchTitle,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data.result);
            location.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your Ajax call is being redirected to the Search page, not the users URL bar if that makes sense. The asynchronous call is being rerouted behind the scenes and that call is hidden from the user.

Comment: Here is some information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely helps clarify what's going on

Comment: HI @DogEars,any update about this case? Is this solution helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like bellow.

Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostStateClickAsync(string state)
{
    //...
     return new JsonResult(new { redirectToUrl = "/Search" });
}
```

In your Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('path').click(function () {
    var stateParameter = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Index?handler=StateClick&state=' + stateParameter,
        //data: searchTitle,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
            }
    });
});
});
```

Test Result:
[image]