# How can redirect to a URL with authorization header?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http, redirect

I am creating a REST end point which need to redirect user to a page after checking Authorization Bearer token for authenticity of request. I have created the end point to redirect using Location header at server side. Till this point its good.

Now I am trying to simulate an action in html that can POST or GET to the above service by passing authorization header. How can i get this redirection working?

I have tried using XMLHttpRequest and ajax requests, but browser handles the redirect on its own and send back the target url content in the success callback. But i would want to open the new tab instead with target URL.

Comment: Normally if you make an AJAX request it should just work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589. How have you built your calling code and what happens?

Comment: if you are using ajax, then you can pass headers from the JS. Either use the session to store the header value OR pass the authorization value in the url parameters

Comment: @ewramner: through ajax, i am able to get the target URL content in success callback. But my requirement is, i want to open the url in new window instead of getting the response text back. Is there any way i can acheive that?

Comment: Update the question to make that clear and add what you have tried. That increases the chance of getting help. However, why don't you simply return the target URL as a normal response (not a redirect), get it in your JavaScript code and open a new window with that location?

Comment: [ewramner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612030/ewramner) Thanks, I have updated the question with what i tried. Have tried ajax calls, but browser handles the redirection on its own and send backs the content of target url in success callback. I would want to redirect user to target URL in new tab. The option to send back target URL is there but since my api will be used by other customers, i wanted to minimize the set of steps required by them to access this api. But for now, looks like that is the only solution. Or I send the token as parameter instead of Auth header. Thoughts on this?