# Getting 302 found in ajax JQUERY request in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using ajax request in Laravel and passing CSRF token also but some times my application gets stuck and getting this error  :

[image]

Code :

```
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        header:$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr('action'),
        type:'POST',
        data:formData,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        success:function(response) {
```

This form is in modal popup :

```
 <form id="user-login" class="login" action="{{ url('login') }}" method="post">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
```

> Controller :

```
  public function login(Request $request)
    {  
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'email' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5'],
        ]);
        if ($validator->passes()) {
        if (\Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 'active','isAdmin'=>'0']) || \Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['contact_number' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 'active','isAdmin'=>'0'])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return response(['success' => true,'message'=>'Successfully Login'], 200);
         }
        else
        {
            $message = 'Invalid username or password';
            return response()->json(['success'=>false,'message' => $message]);
        }
    }
    return Response::json(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);
    }
```

> Route:

```
Route::post('/user-login', 'Auth\UserRegisterController@login')->name('user-login');
```

> RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($guard == "employee" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::EMPLOYEE_HOME);
        }

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: Could you share the controller action. 302 means you get redirected

Comment: @GertB.: I have added my controller code also but this issue is there in all the ajax request but sometimes my application works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

modify the return in controller

```
return response(['success' => true,'message'=>'Successfully Login'], 200);
```

to

```
return response->json(['success' => true,'message'=>'Successfully Login'], 200);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but getting same error

Comment: Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282429/returning-redirect-as-response-to-xhr-request/2573589#2573589

Answer (score 0):

You should try a couple of things.

1. It can be due to the middleware of an outer group that was redirecting the request
2. Your ajax setup to this. to make sure you're grabbing the token

   `$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '<?= csrf_token() ?>' } });`
3. Make sure you return the response properly.

   `return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Success']);`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. The Token is "grabbed" and would throw a 419 error. The way you return the response in point 3 is missing `->json()`