# What happens when an image tag produces a redirect?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, http, redirect

I have following piece of code

```js
let doCall = (url: URL, params: object): Promise<void> => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        ...
        let img = new Image();

        img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve());
        img.addEventListener('error', () => resolve());
        window.setTimeout(() => resolve(), this.maxCallDelayMs);

        img.src = url.toString();
      });
```

This snippet is not really used to load any images, but instead as an HTTP request. The HTTP endpoint though, I am consuming here, is producing some redirects. The number of redirects is case specific. I want to somehow intercept these redirects from Javascript.

I do not aim to intercept these redirects in a way that stops the redirection. I would like to intercept these redirects because the HTTP endpoint enriches the request parameters with information valuable to the Javascript snippet execution.

In order to do so, I am wondering what is actually going on in the background.

I know that if this was a vanilla ajax call like so

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
        ...
        const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', url.toString());
        httpRequest.send();

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
          ...
          resolve();
        };
      });
```

intercepting the requests would be impossible based [on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573589/6566916).

Is it the same case with the initial snippet? Namely, using an `img` tag to consume an endpoint? Meaning that all the redirections will be performed by the browser and the end result would be the loading of an image? Or in my case, the end of the redirection chain with a 200 HTTP status?

Comment: Why don't you just use `fetch` api that can control redirects?

Comment: @Konrad Great question! and the answer is that this snippet should be supported by all sorts of websites and some of them do not support Javascript...

Comment: Do you mean that the user disabled javascript in their browser?

Comment: If the site doesn't support JavaScript, how is the code you posted supposed to work? Also what does it even mean for a "website" to not support JavaScript?

Comment: @Konrad I meant browsers - sorry - I cannot edit the comment now. But @Pointy is also right... In these browsers the `img` cannot be created programmatically...